# Repeated error in < symbol

Tags: debugging, sage

So this is my sage program for getting the list of even fibonacci numbers less than 4000000
but in the for loop line there is a repeated error with the < symbol.
Why is this so ?

```
list1 = [1,1]
a = 1
b = 1
list2 = []
for b < 4000000:
    b = a + b
    list1 += [b]

for i in list1:
    if i%2 == 0:
        list2 += [i]
print list2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the '<' operator but the usage of 'for'.  It looks like in sage, the 'for' loop specifically iterates over fixed lists.  Replace your 'for' with 'while' and you'll get the behavior you want.

A second problem is that instead of the Fibonacci sequence, 'list1' ends up containing all integers because you never update 'a'.

Here's your solution with the two modifications above:

```
list1 = [1,1]

a = 1

b = 1

list2 = []

while b < 4000000:

    temp = a
    a = b
    b = temp + b
    list1 += [b]

for i in list1:

    if i%2 == 0:
        list2 += [i]


print list2
```